# How can I change the default JPA ID field in the Play Framework?

Tags: jpa, playframework

I'm currently creating some POJOs to connect to an existing database called User.  The database already has a userid that I would like to use.  However the framework creates an id field that it appends to the end of the table.  How can I specify that the framework should use the pre-existing userid field and not create a new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`@AttributeOverride`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html):

```
@Entity
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "userid"))
public class User extends Model { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

To define your own primary key, have your models extend GenericModel instead of model and annotate your primary key with @Id. The model class enhances the generic model with an autogenerated id.

```
class User extends GenericModel{
   @Id
   Long userid;
}
```